UPS HAT for Raspberry Pi Zero | DFR0528
I want to use this old ups hat for my custom project, how can I get the 5V 2A via pinouts and use it to the device, and possible boost the output voltage to 5.1V 2A

FEATURES
Standard Raspberry Pi extension ports for connecting other expansion boards.
2A maximum current output for supporting more Raspberry Pi applications.
Auto switching of charge/recharge path, designed to be against power-down.
On-board 5 LEDs for showing the batteries’ status
On-board Maxim fuel gauge IC
Support reading battery information via I2C
Lithium battery charge/discharge protection and over-heating protection
Anti-backflow mainboard power source
SPECIFICATION
Supply Voltage: 4.5~5.5V
Supply Current: (recommend using the adapter with the power of 2A and above)
Power Supply Interface: Micro-USB
Maximum Charge Current: 1.6A
Battery Port: PH2.0-2P or solderable contact
Battery: 3.7 Lithium Battery
Output Voltage: 5V
Maximum Output Current: 2A
Communication Interface: I2C
Dimension: 65x30mm/2.56x1.18”
Mounting Hole Size: 58x23mm/2.83x0.91”
Operating Temperature: -40℃~85℃

If you connect it to zero, what happens? I believe you just connect the battery and power that hat up via USB plug...

@dingo27mobile , i have an old version of the hat , the button combination is not updated on this version , i need to press multiple times
